# How to detect if iPhone is in motion?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, ios10

I am trying to create an app (in swift) that will detect if a iPhone is in motion.

How would I go to approaching this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into getting the data from the accelerometer.

Here is an example of, how you could retrieve the information.

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {
  let queue = OperationQueue()
  motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: queue, withHandler:
    {
      data, error in guard let data = data else { return }
      print("X = \(data.acceleration.x)")
      print("Y = \(data.acceleration.y)")
      print("Z = \(data.acceleration.z)")
    }
  )
} else {
  print("Accelerometer is not available")
}
```

Dont forget to import CoreMotion!

**Updated solution**
Here is a working example of how to get the accelerometer data, if the device is moving with over 10 km/h.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var timer = Timer()
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval() //Calling function with timer
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    // Scheduling timer to Call the function **getSpeed** with the interval of 1 seconds
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.getSpeed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


func getSpeed(){
    
    var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
        speed = Double((locationManager.location?.speed)!)
    
        print(String(format: "%.0f km/h", speed * 3.6)) //Current speed in km/h
    
    //If speed is over 10 km/h
    if(speed * 3.6 > 10 ){
        
        //Getting the accelerometer data
        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable{
            let queue = OperationQueue()
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: queue, withHandler:
                {data, error in
                    
                    guard let data = data else{
                        return
                    }
                    
                    print("X = \(data.acceleration.x)")
                    print("Y = \(data.acceleration.y)")
                    print("Z = \(data.acceleration.z)")
                    
                }
            )
        } else {
            print("Accelerometer is not available")
        }
    
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: How would I make it so that I can have this code run only if the device is moving at a certain speed?

Comment: Look at the new example. Just copy the code to your View.Controller. Don't forget to mark the question as answered, if you feel your question has been answered.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why all the talk about acceleration? It seems to me that the accelerometer, and CoreMotion, doesn't really have anything to do with this. Instead, it's all about CoreLocation, and all the CoreMotion code could be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create an app (in swift) that will detect if a iPhone is in motion.

That might not be possible. Let's say the iPhone is moving steadily in one direction at 3 km/hr. Core Motion cannot detect this because it is not an acceleration! So your only hope would be to use Core Location; that will give you heading and speed based on the GPS, though of course accuracy will be somewhat limited.

Comment: @MathiasGhys your edit is being discussed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374308/obvious-defacement-of-answer-approved?cb=1

Comment: @Luuklag Thank you for letting me know. I noticed it has been rollbacked since.